# How to copy an image to Amazon S3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, copy

I have a problem a copying an image to Amazon S3

I am using the PHP copy function to copy the image from one server to other server ..it works on go-daddy host server. But it doesn't work for S3. Here is the code that is not working:

```
$strSource =http://img.youtube.com/vi/got6nXcpLGA/hqdefault.jpg

copy($strSource ,$dest);
```

$dest is my bucket url with folder present to upload images

Comment: Can you clear up your question a bit?  Do you mean that you migrated your server to EC2?

Comment: Edwin ..yes server is migrated EC2..
In my project there are to option to user to upload image
1) upload button
2) import from url
so in case of import from url they gives the image url. I want to copy this image in my bucket

Comment: Okay, I edited your question to clarify in order to help others find and answer it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you could copy an image to AWS just like that. I would suggest using a library which talks to the AWS server and then running your commands.

Check this - http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

It provides a `REST` implementation for AWS.

For example, if you want to copy your image, you can do:

```
$s3 = new S3($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey);
$s3->copyObject($srcBucket, $srcName, $bucketName, $saveName, $metaHeaders = array(), $requestHeaders = array());
```

`$awsAccessKey` and `$awsSecretKey` are your secret keys for AWS a/c.

Check it out and hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Pushpesh
i have used thie below code but it just works to copy image from one bucket to other
$s3->copyObject($srcBucket, $srcName, $bucketName, $saveName, $metaHeaders = array(), $requestHeaders = array());
i want copy image from any server to bucket
can you help for this

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand your question. Can you please explain so that i could help you?

Comment: In my project there are to option to user to upload image 1) upload button 2) import from url..
upload image from desktop works but  in case of import from url they gives the image url. I want to copy this image in my bucket 
$strSource =http://img.youtube.com/vi/got6nXcpLGA/hqdefault.jpg

copy($strSource ,$dest);

Comment: Ok, you can do `$str=file_get_contents( $strSource);file_put_contents(YOUR_FILE_PATH_AND_NAME, $str);`. Now you can upload this file to AWS and afterwards delete it. Hope that helps.

Comment: i have used the above code and i get warning
[function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
i have put permission also and image not copy to bucket

Comment: Is allow_url_fopen (http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled?

Comment: $strSource ="http://img.youtube.com/vi/got6nXcpLGA/hqdefault.jpg";
     
     $str=file_get_contents($strSource);
     
$strResult =file_put_contents('http://s3.amazonaws.com/custmorebuck/test', $str);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23480/discussion-between-pushpesh-and-sandeep)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have used the [AWS PHP SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/), but the AWS SDKs can come in handy in situations like this.  The SDK can be used in conjunction with IAM roles to grant access to your S3 bucket.  These are the steps:

1. Modify your code to use the PHP SDK to upload the files (if needed).
2. Create an IAM Role and grant the role permission to the needed S3 buckets.
3. When you start your EC2 instance, specify that you want to use the role.

Then your code will automatically use the permissions that you grant that role.  IAM gives the instance temporary credentials that the SDK uses.  These credentials are automatically rotated for you by IAM and EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my examnple from the documentation to copy an object in S3 Bucket

```
public function copyObject($sSourceKey, $sDestKey)
    {
        $this->checkKey($sSourceKey);
        $this->checkKey($sDestKey);

        $bRet = false;

        // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_copyObject
        try {
            $response = $this->_oS3Client->copyObject(
                array(
                    'Bucket' => $this->getBucketName(),
                    'Key' => $sDestKey,
                    'CopySource' => urlencode($this->getBucketName() . '/' . $sSourceKey),
                )
            );

            if (isset($response['LastModified'])) {
                $bRet = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $GLOBALS['error'] = 1;
            $GLOBALS["info_msg"][] = __METHOD__ . ' ' . $e->getMessage();
            $bRet = false;
        }

        return $bRet;
    }
```